# Root doesn‘t have the permission to change a directory owner

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

**I can't change a directory's owner even if I'm root.**

[image]
[image]

*I want to build a NAS by using raspberry 3B+.*

1. So I have created a user named dorm.
2. Then I changed sshd_file in order to restrict SFTP users(dorm) to
   only visit his home directories

[image]

3. Now the user(dorm) doesn't have the write permission. So After I
   google it,I should mkdir a 777 directory at /home/dorm/ .So I made it by root.
4. Then I wanna change its owner by chown -R dorm:dorm
   /home/dorm/Documents. I failed.

Comment: check there is not an immutable flag set with `lsattr`? [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root)

Comment: `No such file or directory while trying to stat dorm`when I typed `lsattr dorm`

Comment: try `lsattr Documents` from the `/home/dorm` directory

Comment: When I typed `lsattr Documents`at`/home/dorm/`,there is nothing echo.

Comment: when I typed `chattr -i Documents`,echo `chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on Documents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its best to remove the user and try again, this is what I did to make it work.

1. log into newly setup raspberry pi as `pi` user, only default logins exist.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ whoami
pi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lslogins -u
 UID USER PROC PWD-LOCK PWD-DENY LAST-LOGIN GECOS
   0 root   84                              root
1000 pi      5                        15:31 ,,,
```

2. add new user `dorm`

```
$ sudo adduser dorm
Adding user `dorm' ...
Adding new group `dorm' (1001) ...
Adding new user `dorm' (1001) with group `dorm' ...
Creating home directory `/home/dorm' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for dorm
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []:
    Room Number []:
    Work Phone []:
    Home Phone []:
    Other []:
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lslogins -u
 UID USER PROC PWD-LOCK PWD-DENY LAST-LOGIN GECOS
   0 root   87                              root
1000 pi      5                        15:31 ,,,
1001 dorm    0                              ,,,
```

3. make a backup and edit your `sshd_config` file,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config-bak
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ diff /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config-bak
122,128d121
<
< Match User dorm
<     X11Forwarding no
<     AllowTcpForwarding no
<     PermitTTY no
<     ForceCommand internal-sftp
<     ChrootDirectory /home/dorm
```

4. restart ssh service with `sudo service sshd restart`
5. change the ownership of the dorm home directory to root.

```
$ sudo chown root:root /home/dorm
$ sudo chmod 755 /home/dorm
```

6. from the dorm user's directory use sudo as the pi user to create the Documents folder and give ownership to the `dorm` user

```
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ ls
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ mkdir Documents
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Documents’: Permission denied
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ sudo mkdir Documents
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  8 18:15 Documents
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ sudo chown -R dorm:dorm Documents
pi@raspberrypi:/home/dorm $ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dorm dorm 4096 Feb  8 18:15 Documents
```

7. test the connection etc. using your IP address from your host computer (ssh should reply `No route to host`)

```
$ sftp dorm@<IP>
dorm@<IP>'s password:
Connected to dorm@<IP>.
sftp>
```

- you can see the created Documents folder and the user number that owns it (dorm's number)

```
sftp> ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x    2 1001     1001         4096 Feb  8 18:15 Documents
```

- you can't move out of the base directory

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
sftp> cd ..
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
```

- you can't put files in the base directory as dorm doesn't have permissions. (file path will need to be altered for your system)

```
sftp> put /Users/<USER>/tmp
Uploading /Users/<USER>/tmp to /tmp
remote open("/tmp"): Permission denied
```

- if you move into `Documents` then you can then upload files

```
sftp> cd Documents
sftp> put /Users/<USER>/tmp
Uploading /Users/<USER>/tmp to /Documents/tmp
/Users/<USER>/tmp                                                                       100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```